# Why does one pattern rule work but not the other?

Tags: svg, makefile, latex, inkscape

I have problems understanding why one pattern rule in my makefile works fine, but not the other, as they look pretty much similar to me. What I'm trying to do is to compile a LaTeX document using a makefile, including a SVG illustrations exported from Inkscape:

```
#Program paths
LATEX = latex
BIBTEX = bibtex
PDFLATEX = pdflatex
INKSCAPE_PATH = inkscape

#Options
LATEX_OPS=-interaction=nonstopmode
BIBTEX_OPS=
PDFLATEX_OPS=
INKSCAPE_OPS=-D -z --export-latex

#File paths
LATEX_PATH=.
PICS_PATH=/path/to/user\ name/pics

all: my_illustration.svg my_pdf_file.pdf

#Generate files for including SVG illustration
%.svg: $(PICS_PATH)/%.svg
    $(INKSCAPE_PATH) $(INKSCAPE_OPS) --file="$^" --export-pdf="$(subst svg,pdf,$^)"

#Generate PDF
%.pdf: $(LATEX_PATH)/%.tex
    -$(LATEX) $(LATEX_OPS) $^
    -$(BIBTEX) $(BIBTEX_OPS) $(LATEX_PATH)/$(subst .pdf,,$@).aux
    $(PDFLATEX) $(PDFLATEX_OPS) $^
    $(PDFLATEX) $(PDFLATEX_OPS) $^
```

Now, generating `my_pdf_file.pdf` alone works fine, but the SVG rule fails:

```
No rule to make target `my_illustration.svg', needed by `all'.  Stop.
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You must compare like to like. What happens when you try `make my_illustration.svg` instead of just `make`? What happens when you use a simpler `PICS_PATH`? What happens when you make `my_illustration.svg` depend on `./my_pdf_file.tex`?

Comment: And `$(PICS_PATH)/my_illustration.svg` exists? Also isn't the recipe for that target generating a pdf file and not an svg file? So isn't that "violating" rule 2 of the [Rules of Makefiles](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/rules-of-makefiles/)?

Comment: Your recipe for svg doesn't output an svg, don't do this. You can define another pdf pattern such as `$(PICS_PATH)/%.pdf: %.svg`

Comment: @user657267 So: change `%.svg: $(PICS_PATH)/%.svg` => `$(PICS_PATH)/%.pdf: $(PICS_PATH)/%.svg` and then `all: $(PICS_PATH)/my_illustration.pdf my_pdf_file.pdf`? This still didn't work however. I also tried removing `$(PICS_PATH)/`from both "all" and the other rule.

Comment: That error means make decided your pattern rule didn't match.  Since the target clearly matches the pattern, it must be that the prerequisite didn't exist, or as Etan said above, `$(PIC_PATH)/my_illustration.svg` did not exist and could not be created.  If you run `make -d` and examine the steps make takes trying to build the `my_illustration.svg` target you'll see the problem pretty quickly, I'm guessing.

Comment: @MadScientist Thanks, it was a helpful flag to add…but I'm still back at zero. The file exists and the output seems to try to match all kinds of suffixes to the stem anyway. You gave me a hint that led into a workaround however: as `$(PIC_PATH)/my_illustration.svg` doesn't seem to match, I ended up removing the dependency and instead substituting the input file string, which worked in the end, even if it feels like a workaround hack. Thanks anyhow.

Comment: If you add the `-r` option you can remove all built-in implicit rules which, if you don't use them, will simplify the `-d` output.  However, the answer to your question was there, just hard to find.  You need to find the part of the output where it matches your target pattern, then it will try to build the dependency.  You need to look at those lines where it tries to build the dependency file and see why make rejected it.  It _will_ tell you.   If I understand your workaround correctly, the problem is if there's no prerequisite than changing the `PIC_PATH/file` won't update your local file.

Comment: Just to point out, your example worked for me after I ran `touch /path/to/user/pics/my_illustration.svg`, so there's something about your setup which is not reflected in your question: this makes it hard to help.  Did you try this exact example?  Or is this a cut-down version which hasn't been shown to have the same problem as the full version?

Comment: @MadScientist You are right: the posted example is really an example. The difference that may matter, however, is that my real path contains a space, which I have to escape using a backslash. I have changed my example to a more similar path situation.
One more thing: if the inkscape generated file have succeeded earlier – using my substitution workaround, for example – then, `make` sees that the resulting output file exists and skips checking for the SVG file. This is expected though, but I'm mentioning it nonetheless.

Comment: @MadScientist Wow, couldn't even imagine I was going to tumble down this rabbit hole: it's very likely that white space that is the issue… http://www.cmcrossroads.com/article/gnu-make-meets-file-names-spaces-them

Comment: Oh.  Yes.  You can't use whitespace in target or prerequisite names and have much success.  That's unquestionably your problem.  As the Dr. says, "just don't do that".